# Using Facebook PHP SDK to access multiple pages

Tags: facebook

I am using the Facebook PHP SDK to retrieve FB posts and display them on websites for 2 organizations.

I was using a single FB app to retrieve the data from both Facebook pages using the PHP SDK.

Since Facebook reviewed and approved my app, I can now only access the posts from the FB page of the owner of the app.

> I'm getting an access denied message for the other FB page.

Any ideas on how I would get the needed permissions required, or, the steps I need to take so I can access the FB posts from the other page?

Comment: Make the user an admin on the second page, or get an access token for someone who is an admin of that page. Barring that, there's a "Page Public Content Access" permission, but I'm not sure your use case will be approved.

Comment: please always include the relevant parts of your code, or at least the exact api call, and (even more important) the exact error/debug messages. anyway, for pages you do not own, you must apply for page public content access, as ceejayoz mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your responses... ceejayoz, how do I get an access token for someone who is an admin of the other page?